# tcsh: make 2-digit hours in prompt

Tags: environment-variables, prompt, tcsh

I am attempting to simply get a standard lexigraphical time display in the prompt and the history file in the range of 00:00:00 to 23:59:59. I've tried

```
set prompt=%P$
```

but this just produces, for example,

```
7:12:43$
```

when time is before noon. I need it to display `07:12:43` instead so that the times sort correctly and the widths are uniform. Can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can get this behavior with `set padhour`:

```
ubuntu:~> set prompt="%P>"
0:36:02>
0:36:03>set padhour
00:36:07>
```

Also tested on FreeBSD 10.

From the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/tcsh.1.html):

```
Special shell variables
    padhour If set, enable the printing of padding '0' for hours,
            in 24 and 12 hour formats.  E.G.: 07:45:42 vs. 7:45:42.
```

Comment: Thanks, but apparently my version of tcsh (6.14) doesn't implement this shell variable. I will need to update the shell to try it.

Comment: OK. If you have the source to your version, adding support for `padhour` is a 2-line change to the code. The diff on github is here: https://github.com/tcsh-org/tcsh/commit/59791f76c858a293b826ca28b301dabf57a59dbd

Comment: Thanks but I'm on a corporate server. I wouldn't even know who to ask to recompile. It's on tsch 6.14.00 (Astron) 2005-03-25.

Comment: How hard is it to just run a private shell version?

Comment: If you put the new shell in, say, `~thomas/bin/tcsh`, you can put `setenv SHELL ~thomas/bin/tcsh; $SHELL` in your `~/.login` to run it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put this in the begining (or anywhere else you want) of your PS1 variable in your .tcshrc file:

```
\D{%H:%M:%S}
```

For example:

```
PS1='(\D{%H:%M:%S}) <\u@\h\W>'
```

The time will be the time when you get the prompt back, it wont update as time goes by.

Comment: This is a `tcsh` question, not `bash`.